# Настройка клиента OpenVPN

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openvpn

У меня есть настроенный OpenVPN клиент на windows. Соответственно есть публичный ключ, приватный ключ, конфиг vpn. В качестве пароля используется второй фактор. Я хочу подключить аналогичный vpn клиент на другой машине с Ubuntu 20.04, используя уже имеющиеся ключи, конфиг. Как это можно сделать? Куда вводить второй фактор? Ввод в поле password - не срабатывает.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *Куда вводить второй фактор?* — смотря что вы подразумеваете под «вторым фактором». одноразовый пароль? ну так его и надо вводить при каждом подключении. а в настройках оставьте поле пустым.

Answer (score 0):

По крайней мере на Ubuntu 21.04 встроeнна поддержка клиента OpenVPN.   Перекинуть папку с файлом конфига и файлы ключей на Ubuntu:

Setting - network - Add vpn - import from file.